# How do I get the current language in Play Framework 2.7

Tags: playframework, migration, translation

I'm migrating from Play Framework 2.6 to version 2.7.

In this version, they deprecated a lot of stuff that I was using. One of them is the `Lang` methods as you can see in their migration page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaHttpContextMigration27#Lang-and-Messages-methods-in-Http.Context-deprecated

Since I mainly use Play as a plain back-end API, I'm not using any views but for some calls, I need to know what is the current language so I can return translated values.

The problem is that I can't find any ways to **get** the current language. All the examples show ways to change/clear the current language or how to use it in Views but I just want to query the current language.

For example, my old code:

`play.api.i18n.Lang lang = ctx().lang();`

Or this:

`lang().code()`

How can I achieve a similar result with Play 2.7 + ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get it by injecting MessagesApi.

Like this in a controller (written directly in this wysiwyg, not tested):

```
@Inject
private MessagesApi messagesApi;

public Result index(Http.Request request) {
    Lang currentLang = messagesApi.preferred(request).lang()
    String langStr = currentLang.code();

    return ok();
}
```

Comment: I was considering the `preferred` method but since it's not a "get" and based on some sort of query, I wasn't sure. Will definitely try it to see if it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not a "get""?Is your function triggered entirely on "it's own" from the backend (e.g. from a scheduler) or is it triggered by an external request?

Comment: it's triggered by a controller, no worries there, I have an external request. I'm in the process of testing it all, will comment here after :)